# Selecting a particular DOM element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following code in my HTML:

```
<li class="strange">1</li>

<li class="strange">2</li>

<li class="strange">3</li>

<li class="strange">4</li>
```

I want to choose the exact `<li>` which contains number `'3'` as a Text.

Is there any method to choose the exact element?

Can we choose by using some OO-JS methods?

Comment: using jquery `$('li:contains("3")')` will return object of li which contains 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using jQuery  selector [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

> Description: Select all elements that contain the specified text.

```
$('li:contains("3")')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/58grs1w7/)

**Match exact text**

As per @Raoulito mention in his comment here updated answer which match exact text using jQuery  [filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/).

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match
>   the selector or pass the function's test.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("li").filter(function() {
   return $(this).text() === "3";
  }).css("color", "red");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/58grs1w7/2/)

Comment: Although this method can be a bit unprecise as it selects all the elements _containing_ "3" meaning "0.3" and "13" would also be selected.

Comment: yes you are right . check i have update my answer which matched exact text . Thank you for find this point  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with jQuery [contains](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)

```
$('li:contains("3")');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xzpprdxs/)**

Answer (score 0):

This only select the element which has exactly '3' as text:

```
$('li.strange').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).text() == '3' ) {
        $(this).css('color','red');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dremztou/1/

`$('li.strange:contains("3")').addClass('selected');` would select all the elements containing 3, including 13, 23, 33, etc.

Comment: Oooh yes, sorry for the snatch! : )

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript you can do like:

```
 var list = document.getElementsByClassName("strange");

 for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
if(list[i].innerHTML ==3)
  {
    list[i].style.color = "blue";
     list[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
   }
 }
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/051Lx5xs/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use just javascript you can do something like that:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="ul">
    <li class="strange">1</li>
    <li class="strange">2</li>
    <li class="strange">3</li>
    <li class="strange">4</li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
var nums = document.getElementById("ul"); // get the ul element
var listItem = nums.getElementsByClassName("strange"); //fetch all elements inside the ul that have a class of strange

var element;

// loop through the list elements
for (var i=0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
    // check whether list's inner html is equal to 3
    if (parseInt( listItem[i].innerHTML) == 3) {
        // set the value of element equal to the list element
        element = listItem[i];
        break;
    }
}

console.log(element); // logs out the element that has the required value, you can use element.innerHTML to check
```